# Magento 2: what's wrong about the cart process?

Tags: magento2, cart

Magento version: 2.0.0

I added a product into cart, and then print the $_SESSION:

```
[checkout] => Array
        (
            [last_added_product_id] => 5
        )

    [message] => Array
        (
            [default] => Magento\Framework\Message\Collection Object
                (
                    [messages:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [success] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Magento\Framework\Message\Success Object
                                        (
                                            [text:protected] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
                                                (
                                                    [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => You added %1 to your shopping cart.
                                                    [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Demo Product
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [identifier:protected] => default_message_identifier
                                            [isSticky:protected] => 
                                            [data:protected] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [lastAddedMessage:protected] => Magento\Framework\Message\Success Object
                        (
                            [text:protected] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
                                (
                                    [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => You added %1 to your shopping cart.
                                    [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Demo Product
                                        )

                                )

                            [identifier:protected] => default_message_identifier
                            [isSticky:protected] => 
                            [data:protected] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

Add to Cart Form Code:

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>" />
                                                            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                                            <button type="submit"
                                                                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </form>
```

I checked the `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart`:

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @return int
 */
public function getItemsCount()
{
//      echo '<pre>';
//      print_r($_SESSION);
//      echo '</pre>';
//      exit();
    return $this->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
}
```

I open the cart page is empty and found this `$this->getQuote()->getItemsCount()` is still empty.

So, I don't know where is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `getItemsCount` method is defined under `Magento/Quote/Model/Quote`:

```
public function getItemsCount()
{
    return $this->_getData(self::KEY_ITEMS_COUNT);
}
```

It retrieves the data of the quote based on the constant `const KEY_ITEMS_COUNT = 'items_count';` of the quote class.

Comment: yes, i have found this function. i have added the product into cart and the product data is added into $_SESSION. i don't know why it is still empty.

Comment: @MikeZhang well that's not exactly the question you asked. Create a new question with the code you used to add the product to cart and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: I have updated this question, could check it again, thanks.